# How to fix 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' after adding it to the build path and registered using Class.forName();

Tags: java, mysql, http, servlets

I had added mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar from build path in Eclipse Jee. I 
had also registered that class by adding :

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

but still it is giving me this error :

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

This is the code of Student.java Servlet.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Student extends HttpServlet
{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        // business logic
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sem5", "root", "root");

            String sql = "insert into p4 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            String enroll = request.getParameter("enroll");
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");
            String address = request.getParameter("address");


            ps.setString(1, enroll.toString());
            ps.setString(2, username.toString());
            ps.setString(3, password.toString());
            ps.setString(4, gender.toString());
            ps.setString(5, email.toString());
            ps.setString(6, mobile.toString());
            ps.setString(3, address.toString());

            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception : "+ ex);
            out.println("Error");
        }
    }
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        doGet(request,response);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That's the wrong class name if you are using Connector 8.0 or later.

Comment: And it shouldn't be in the **build** path. It should be in the **runtime** classpath, i.e. under WEB-INF/lib in your generated war file.

Comment: @JBNizet how do i add jar file in WEB-INF/lib...?

Comment: It depends on how you're building your application. Assuming you're using Eclipse (which is the only tool using the term "build path" AFAIK), you just drop the jar in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib of your web project IIRC.

Comment: @JBNizet Eclipse dosen't allow me to drop the jar file in WebContent/WEB_INF/lib folder...

Comment: Then use your file explorer or your command line to put it there. http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwplib.html

Comment: You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` at all since 2007. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` instead of `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` while using MySQL connector 8. Please refer the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).

Comment: ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver``` still getting this error using ```Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();```

Comment: are you using Tomcat to run the servlet? In that case, you may need to copy the connector to tomcat/lib folder as well. I've seen an error previously while working with tomcat server.

Comment: yes i am using tomcat server v7.0 to run my program... Can you please give me the location of tomcat/lib folder.

Comment: <path-to-tomcat-installation-folder-in-your-machine>/lib