# Unable to connect to mysql with jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

I have a java file `hello.java`, which has a JDBC connection , while running it, I am getting the error(**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**) :

```
javac hello.java
java hello
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at hello.main(hello.java:22)
Goodbye!
```

And when I try with the classpath, it gives :

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar hello.java
java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar hello

Error: Could not find or load main class hello
```

I also tried with **mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar**, still the same issue.

And `java -version` gives :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

I tried the following questions :

1. [ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585811/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)
2. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error even after importing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254131/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-error-even-after-importi)
3. [How to fix 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' after adding it to the build path and registered using Class.forName();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57335885/how-to-fix-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-after-addin)
4. [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse)

But got no satisfactory result. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code, `hello.java` :

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages 
import java.sql.*; 

public class hello { 

    // JDBC driver name and database URL 
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/data"; 

    // Database credentials 
    static final String USER = "newuser"; 
    static final String PASS = "password"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Connection conn = null; 
        Statement stmt = null; 

        try{ 

        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

        //STEP 3: Open a connection System.out.println("Connecting to database..."); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS); 
        //STEP 4: Execute a query 
        System.out.println("Creating statement..."); 

        stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
        String sql; 
        sql = "SELECT * from temp"; 
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 

        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set 
        while(rs.next()){ 

            //Retrieve by column name 
            int id = rs.getInt("id"); 
            int age = rs.getInt("age"); 
            String first = rs.getString("first"); 
            String last = rs.getString("last"); 

            //Display values System.out.print("ID: " + id); 
            System.out.print(", Age: " + age); 
            System.out.print(", First: " + first); 
            System.out.println(", Last: " + last); 

        } 
        //STEP 6: Clean-up environment 
        rs.close(); 
        stmt.close(); 
        conn.close(); 

        }catch(Exception e){ 
            //Handle errors for JDBC 
            e.printStackTrace(); 

        } finally{ 
            //finally block used to close resources 
            try{ 
                if(stmt!=null) {
                    stmt.close(); 
                }
            }catch(SQLException se){ 
            // nothing we can do 
            se.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            try{ 
                if(conn!=null) conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){ 
                se.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
        }//end main 
    }//end FirstExample

}
```

Comment: And there should be no need for that `Class.forName()` - this has been obsoleted for years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do in this way.

```
javac hello.java

java -cp .:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar hello
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060341/classnotfoundexception-in-jdbc-program-despite-of-adding-drivers-jar-file/66061405#66061405).